Excel VBA 32-Bit to 64-Bit
I have a old Excel file with 32-bit code.
Who can turn this into 64-Bit code?
Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" ( _
                 ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                 ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
                 ByVal x As Long, _
                 ByVal y As Long, _
                 ByVal cx As Long, _
                 ByVal cy As Long, _
                 ByVal wFlags As Long) _
                 As Long
Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Thanks for your help

Who can turn this into 64-Bit code? - you can.

Maybe this sheds some more light on the issue. In this case you need to change Longptr  for hwnd and hWndInsertAfter. And you need to add the keyword Ptrsafe.

Really helpful with many examples is JKP's article Declaring API functions for 64 bit Office and Mac Office

Further reading  compatibility 32bit Excel and 64 bit Excel office 365 shows how to use conditional compile constants including helpful comments by @GSerg

The original Microsoft link has been retired but I created a gist to hold useful API declarations.

@CristianBuse Impressive work & documentation!

@T.M. I simply saved the file in the same state as I downloaded from Microsoft many years ago. The copyright from Microsoft is at the top of the file so I did not think to mention - I did not write any line of code :) But the documentation is indeed impressive.

In this case it is
Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
    ByVal hWndInsertAfter As LongPtr, _
    ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, _
    ByVal cx As Long, _
    ByVal cy As Long, _
    ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Further reading 1, 2, 3
